# How to allow / workaround nested composite Gradle builds

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

I'm running into the same issue as reported [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1909):

> I have a Java project A which depends on project B (module), and
>   project B dependes on project C (another module). For project A I
>   would like to setup "includeBuild ../projectB" and for project B I
>   would like too setup "includeBuild ../projectC" so that I could
>   develop everything in Eclipse + Buildship 2.0 without the need to run
>   Gradle for every small change in each of the projecta A, B and C.
>
> But if I setup this I get: "Included build '%s' cannot have included
>   builds.".
>
> Expected Behavior
>
> Recursive "includeBuild" would recursively include dependent projects.
>
> Current Behavior
>
> I get "Included build '%s' cannot have included builds.".
>
> Your Environment
>
> Gradle 3.5, Buildship 2.0, Eclipse 3.6

How can I resolve / work around this issue? In my instance, I have utility project that includes email functionality (using JavaMail). The email functionality is needed in the data project and a UI project. The UI project also depends on the data project.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Adding another answer for a different approach...

Each `settings.gradle` could add a check to before `includeBuild` to see if it's already inside a composite. If it's already inside a composite, it doesn't `includeBuild`.

See [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-identify-if-module-runs-within-composite-build/23219/9) for extra info on the composite check

Eg

`project2/settings.gradle`

```groovy
boolean inComposite = gradle.parent != null
if (!inComposite) {
    includeBuild '../project1'
}
```

`project3/settings.gradle`

```groovy
boolean inComposite = gradle.parent != null
if (!inComposite) {
    includeBuild '../project1'
    includeBuild '../project2'
}
```

`project4/settings.gradle`

```groovy
boolean inComposite = gradle.parent != null
if (!inComposite) {
    includeBuild '../project1'
    includeBuild '../project2'
    includeBuild '../project3'
}
```

etc etc

Using this approach you could run `gradle` from wherever you like and it should behave as expected (ie substitute dependencies with local projects)

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered

1. Ensuring that none of the individual builds are composite builds
2. Having an "uber" build which is a composite of everything

Note that the `settings.gradle` is itself a groovy script, so you could create a dynamic composite, eg all sub-folders with a build.gradle under a parent.

uber/settings.gradle

```groovy
new File("c:/someFolder").listFiles().each { File f ->
    if (f.directory && new File(f, 'build.gradle').exists()) {
        includeBuild f
    }
}
```

Eg

```
c:/someFolder/project1/build.gradle
c:/someFolder/project1/src/main/java/**/*.java
c:/someFolder/project2/build.gradle
c:/someFolder/project2/src/main/java/**/*.java
c:/uber/settings.gradle (as above)
```

Comment: Actually it is a little confusing. Can you demonstrate with a folder structure. Taking above case as an example. Thanks in advance

Comment: See sample folder structure. Basically you would checkout all your individual projects to a common folder. Then the `uber` build would compose them all together. If you wanted to put the `uber` project in the same folder you could add an exclusion for it in `settings.gradle` to stop it including itself

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But by this way I cannot include project1 as a dependency for project2 right.

Comment: Yes, you can. project2 would reference project1 by `GAV `(group,artifact,version). As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/composite_builds.html#composite_build_intro) "If any build in the composite has a dependency that can be satisfied by the included build, then that dependency will be replaced by a project dependency on the included build"

Comment: Note: You'd run all commands through the uber build to benefit from the composite. Running gradle from the individual builds would pickup dependencies from the repository, NOT the composite